# dual-port parallel-to-serial SRAM?

Tags: sram, esp32

I wanna interface an old Motorola 68000-based system with an ESP32, and I was thinking of doing that through SRAM. However I can't seem to find any SRAM that I could put between them. What other options do I have?

The idea was to stick this hypothetical dual-port SRAM straight on the 68k bus and on the ESP32's external RAM interface (QSPI/OSPI).

Comment: which 68000 system, in particular? You'd typically just use one of the communication ports that your microprocessor (or microcontroller) has. However, there are literally hundreds of different chips with an 68000 core, so it's impossible to tell what you need. Also, you'll need to tell us what data / for which purpose you're communicating; makes little sense else.

Comment: @MarcusMüller the system basically exposes the 68k bus directly, for the most part.

Comment: I don't know the electrical and logical structure of that; and I'd guess it'd be different for the 24 bit and 32 bit variants logically, and electrically totally depend on the individual chip. So, would it really be too much to tell us which chip or system we're talking about, in particular? You're literally asking the same as "I want to connect my x86 to my ARM for unspecified reasons", and I hope you understand why I think that's a bit too unspecific.

Comment: no, it really is a literal Motorola 68000. not a 680x0. this is more comparable to saying I have an 8086 than an x86.

Comment: Parallel to parallel dual port SRAM is easy to find (or used to be, when the 68000 wasn't quite so retro). To do what you're asking, the logical choice would be a small FPGA, then you get to write exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Is the SRAM purely for communicating between the 68000 and the ESP32?  How much did you want?

Comment: If it's only small requirement, have you consider IDT7130? 1k x 8, parallel both sides, available in through-hole to match your 68000 https://www.idt.com/eu/en/document/dst/713040-datasheet

Comment: depends, does "shared memory" count as "purely for communicating"? I want 4MB ideally.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please appreciate that it's not a free design house. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your work and findings so far in considerable detail with any schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome.

Comment: seriously considering the "DRAM + FPGA" option tbh.

Comment: Are you just building one?  Wondering if you need through-hole or will make a surface mount PCB?

Comment: _"I want 4MB ideally"_ - Why?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very good application for a small FPGA. If you don't need much shared memory, you can use block RAM inside the FPGA. Otherwise, a small parallel SRAM or DRAM should suffice.